# Dating in Style Savvy: Trendsetters?

Tags: style-savvy-trendsetters

Can I date in Style Savvy: Trendsetters? Brad and Dominic are some of the guys that flirt and seem interested in you. I've gone out on dates with Brad, but he won't make a move. Does anything ever happen?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear to be possible. Once you build a good customer relationship with some of the boys you can go to events with them and take photos, but there's nothing like actual dating or relationships. [Discussion thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/680013-style-savvy-trendsetters/64534341)

However, it appears that the Japanese version got an update last year where you could create an actual boyfriend and do more relationship-like things. I don't think this game mode ever made it outside of Japan. [Link](http://www.siliconera.com/2014/02/28/create-dream-boyfriend-style-savvy-trendsetters-new-mode-japan/)